# Is Trump's COVID-19 liability waiver enforceable?

Tags: united-states, liability, waivers, oklahoma

In order to get tickets to Donald Trump's campaign rally this weekend, you're required to agree to the following waiver of liability:

> By clicking register below, you are acknowledging that an inherent risk of exposure to COVID-19 exists in any public place where people are present. By attending the Rally, you and any guests voluntarily assume all risks related to exposure to COVID-19 and agree not to hold Donald J. Trump for President, Inc.; BOK Center; ASM Global; or any of their affiliates, directors, officers, employees, agents, contractors, or volunteers liable for any illness or injury.

Is this legally enforceable?

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/29240/waiver-of-liability-can-i-be-required-to-waive-an-institution-from-liability-fr seems partly relevant.

Comment: @NateEldredge, I wonder if the participant has been convinced by the party who wants to be shielded then does assumption of risk apply?  "Sign this form waiving liability for this activity which is clearly a safe one." The gross misconduct is probably denying the risk in the first place.